# I have a Python program that the customer would like to access as a double clickable desktop icon on Windows 8. How do I do this? 8

Tags: python, windows-8

I have a  program called ftpgrab.py.  At the command prompt  to  run it I type:

`c:\path\to\python\dir\python.exe ftpgrab.py`

Is there a way on  Windows 8  to create  an  icon which I  can double-click to  run this?

Comment: I am tempted to use a hammer on the Win 8 machine but would lose customer. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you used one of the standard installers for python on windows, .py is already registered and it should just work. Copy it to your desktop and double-click. A console running the program should appear and run as normal. Its still a console app - the the customer wants a gui app, that's a different story.

btw, you shouldn't even have to type `c:\path\to\python\dir\python.exe ftpgrab.py`, just a plain `ftpgrab.py` or `ftpgrab` should do.

Answer (score 4):

You can either create a batch file that will launch the program, or use something like [pyinstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) to transform your script into an executable that can be run directly.

Answer (score 2):

1. create a file named `foo.bat`;
2. copy your command to that file and save it;
3. double click `foo.bat`...